# Check for undefined field

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

```js
const method = <
  B extends string, 
  BB extends B extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no' = B extends undefined ? 'yes' : 'no'
>({
  b,
  bb,
}: {
  b?: B;
  bb: `${BB}`;
}) => {};

method({ bb: 'yes' }); // Type '"yes"' is not assignable to type '"no"'.
```

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAExgXhgHgEIwIAeUCYaEM0ATgJZgDmANDHgcaeZeyWRTAFdyCAGb0EGAPwwA5AE8EEGTABcssCGXYenfkLSjxU2QqWr1mgHwAKAN4AoGDABGTRy9f2AvmodPnkmp4ANzuzs5qAAYAJLZsXpGhXgCUWJYwtl6h9ogo6HYeavKKyinBQA)

Why does the check for undefined not work and is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Is this really a [**minimal** reproducible example](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Also, proper names rather than easily-confused things like `B` and `BB` would help people help you. It would also help to have a description of what the type parameters on `method` are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `B extends string`, `B extends undefined` can ever be true, so the false branch is always taken. If you want to allow `B` to be `undefined`, you have to allow it in `B`'s constraints:

```typescript
const method = <
    B extends string | undefined, // <====================
    BB extends B extends undefined ? "yes" : "no" = B extends undefined ? "yes" : "no"
>({
    b,
    bb,
}: {
    b?: B;
    bb: `${BB}`;
}) => {};

method({ bb: "yes" });         // <== Works
method({ b: "x", bb: "yes" }); // <== Error, since `B` is not `undefined`
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgUygCxAExgXhgHgFAyEwBCMCAHlAmGhDNAE4CWYA5jAD4wCuNCAZiwRoANDAD043Jhmy58+QSLFSFKjTqrK1Wjz6CwwmAH4YAIgCeCCGZgAuc2BC3sW9bt5oBQjKcvXbBzMnMzwAPgAKAG8lQgAjEViYOIS8AF8HGKJk4wdiAG4klIcAAwASKJU0ksK0gEosMJgotMK8RBR0aOS4oKsbGHr87JHJaWwAdRAGAGsIdqRUNG7e83IzMWLzftshiSkcGRgAUQYGabEIFmAEGBLiEpgmOidYEs9vQzQSoA)

Comment: But is it a symbol `?` does not mean that the field can be undefined?

Comment: I assume you mean the `?` in `b?: B`. It means it can be *absent*, which in effect means its type can be `undefined`, but that's something that's added to its declared type. For example, `x?: string` means `x` ends up with the type `string | undefined`. So `b?: B` means `b` ends up with the type `B | undefined`, not that **`B`**, itself, contains `undefined`.